# How to place overlay over image using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, image

Desired Effect: An image (and only the image) should darken when a user hovers over it.

Plan: Use .mouseenter with JQuery to implement the desired effect.

Problem: When a user hovers over image, the overlay applies to something else (#Bars), despite using the same selector for both .mouseenter and also for appending the overlay. So the overlay works properly, but it isn't applying to the image. I tested the overlay by appending it to the body, and this does work (that is, when I hover over the image, the entire body of the webpage darkens). I even tested it on the nav bar, and once again, it works (when I hover over the image, the nav bar darkens). Unfortunately, the one thing that I want to append it to, the image, doesn't work.

Attempted Solutions: I've added IDs to ul, li, a, and the img, and I have tried selecting several combinations of these, but nothing has worked. I've also tried adding a high z-index in the CSS to #overlay, just in case it was lower than the picture. This didn't work.

Question: Which selector should I use to achieve the desired effect?

html.erb

```
<ul id="Bars">
    <li id="bar1photo" class="barphoto"><%= link_to(image_tag("bar1.jpg", id: "bar1image"), bar1_path, id: "bar1") %></li>
    <li id="bar2photo" class="barphoto"><%= link_to(image_tag("bar2.jpg", id: "bar2image"), bar2_path, id: "bar2") %></li>
<ul>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    $("li#bar1photo a")
        .mouseenter(function(){

            $("li#bar1photo a").append($overlay.show());

        })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $overlay.hide();
        });
});
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot add the overlay element to the HTML directly instead of using jQuery? You could do something like this and skip the jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/pu0k2bf9/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent need a `relative` position.

```
.barphoto {
 position: relative;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/onrv7j9g/) here.

Answer (score 1):

i whould do somthing like that:

```
$("li#bar1photo a").on('mouseover',function(){
  $(this).parent("li").addClass('overlay');
});
```

and the css somthing like that:

```css
.overlay {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: Your jQuery adds a class to the `li` element which already has a class `.barphoto` the OP could hook into. The code you have supplied adds styles to the `li`which will not provide the overlay effect.

Comment: what's OP mean?... there is no problem to add more then one class to element... i figured from the question that the li holding the image as background-image isn't it?

Comment: OP = `Original Poster` = the person who asked the question. Of course you can have more than one class on an element. Creating a utility class can be useful as I believe that was part of what you were suggesting in your answer but the OP wants an overlay that will effectively darken the image when it is hovered. Changing the background of the `li` will not darken the image when hovered.